# Alias for a function of a pointer to an object

Tags: c++

I am making a game with a separate map class and a separate renderer class for rendering the map.

Here is a simplified version of what that looks like: (the function I am interested in is `renderMap()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Map
{
public:
    Map(int mapSize)
        : data(mapSize,3) {} //Initialize the vector with the requested size, filled with 3's. Just as an example

    //Accessors
    const std::vector<int>& accessData() { return data; }

private:
    std::vector<int> data;
};

class Renderer
{
public:
    void setPointerToMap(Map& map) { pointerToMap = &map; }

    void renderMap()
    {
        // Here some of the calls to the map object might become really long, especially if the vector "data" contains objects and we need to access the objects
        // So can we somehow create a short alias for "pointerToMap->accessData()"?
        // So that instead of "pointerToMap->accessData()[0]" we write "dataPoint[0], for example

        std::cout << pointerToMap->accessData()[0];
    }
private:
    Map* pointerToMap;
};

int main()
{
    Map map(5);  // Create map object

    Renderer renderer;  // Create renderer object

    renderer.setPointerToMap(map);   // "Attach" the map to the renderer by giving the renderer a pointer to the map

    renderer.renderMap();  // Render the map in the renderer using the pointer to the map to read the data
}
```

So basically I read the data of Map inside Renderer using a pointer to the `map` object.
I've read about `using` keyword and function pointers, but can't figure out if they are intended to be used for this.

I tried making a function pointer like this:

```
std::vector<int>& (Map:: * dataPoint)() = pointerToMap->accessData;
```

but this gives an error
`error C3867: 'Map::accessData': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member`
and Visual Studio says that "a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function.
So I guess it is simply not possible to create a function pointer if we access the function with a pointer?

If we make the `data` vector public, then we can access it:

```
std::vector<int>& dataPoint = pointerToMap->data;
std::cout << dataPoint[0];
```

But that's not exactly what I need in my actual game.

Bonus: Here is the other way that I managed to create a function pointer inside `renderMap()`, yet I don't understand how it works and it doesn't really work correctly:

```
std::vector<int>& (Map:: * dataPoint)() = &Map::accessData;
std::cout << dataPoint;
```

So the question is, is it possible to shorten the function calls in this case and how?

Comment: Tip: Don't forget to flag member functions as `const` if they don't modify your object. `const std::vector<int>& accessData() const { ... }`

Comment: Exposing details in the function name is kind of redundant. Just do `setMap(Map*)` and take a pointer. This makes it very clear to the caller how that data is used. Taking a pointer from a reference is *sneaky and bad* as the caller may not know they're now obligated to keep that object alive indefinitely. Even better, use `std::shared_ptr` to share pointers.

Comment: @tadman raw pointers are really fine for that. `Map` has a known lifetime that is longer than the `Renderer`, so using shared pointer is a waste there, and would actually hide the known lifetimes onto runtime territory instead of compile time. Raw pointers are the right thing here.

Comment: @tadman yeah, I usually use the first tip, just forgot in this example. Second one is quite good though, I wasn't sure whether to pass it by reference or pointer, but this tip is quite logical so I will use it now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `accessData` on each line, simply create a reference and use it for all other lines:

```
const std::vector<int>& dataPoint = pointerToMap->accessData();

std::cout << dataPoint[0];
```

Here you create a new variable that is a reference to the vector returned by `accessData`.

Comment: Thanks!
This is pretty much what I needed :)